# Popcorn js getting ogg in Safari 5

Tags: javascript, safari, popcornjs

Popcorn isn't playing in safari 5 and the reason seems to be that the popcorn is asking for ogg as opposed to mp4.  It's bizarre because safari 6 is receiving mp4.

Is there any way to override popcorn asking for ogg and have it instead get mp4?

EDIT

Here is a code sample...

```
<video height="240" width="320" id="video-one">
    <source src="http://localhost:8000/static/scratch-flv/rmR7FDgeEeKM0GD7QvFn-g.mp4" class="video-source-240">
    <source src="http://localhost:8000/static/scratch-flv/rmR7FDgeEeKM0GD7QvFn-g.ogg" class="video-source-240">
</video>
```

Comment: Popcorn doesn't usually care what the source format is. It will play anything that will play in the video element. How are you setting the source?

Comment: I have a bunch of images that when clicked sets a video element that is passed around amongst them.  I'm setting the source with mp4 and ogg filetypes.

Comment: Do you have mp4 first?  If you want to post a link to some code, I can take a look.

Comment: I just posted the markup above.  If you want to see this in action have a look here: http://stkr.fm/52U  Also, I see you are New York, if you ever have time to talk about html5 video I would love to meet up!

Comment: It's playing just fine for me in Safari.

Have you considered using webm in addition to or instead of ogg? It's higher quality than ogg/theora, and the only browser that supports ogg but not mp4 or webm is Firefox < 4.0.

Comment: What is your version of Safari?

Comment: Safari 6.0.2. What's yours?

Comment: Same, 6.0.  This is a problem I'm only experiencing in 5.  I'm testing it on my friend's computer and the network tab in inspector is showing that it is trying to get ogg.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20199/discussion-between-brianchirls-and-captdaylight)